# Переключиться на пользователя в yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Yii2. Шаблон advanced. 
Использую модуль yii2-user от dektrium. 
Использую разные сессии во фронтедне и бэкенде. 
Когда хочу через бэкенд переключиться на другого юзера, переключает в бэкенде, однако мне надо, чтобы сессия поменялась во фронтенде. Как это реализовать?

Comment: в main.php для фронта пропишите значения для identityCookie как в админском конфиге как обсуждается в https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/issues/110

Comment: Это не поможет. Сессия все равно будет меняться в бэкенде.